# Which appliance to use for masala chai?

Tags: tea, indian-cuisine, chai

Many regions have special devices or at least custom namings to brew tea and similar beverages:

- *Teapot* in Western countries
- *Caydalnik* in Turkey
- *Samovar* in Russia
- *Samavar* in Kashmir

Is there any special appliance, either a corresponding naming of such for brewing masala chai?

Comment: I am curious for an answer other than a regular pan.

Answer (score 3):

In my house, we have a rectangular-cylindrical metal pot that is used to make only chai. It does not have a specific name, although the class of utensils that it comes from are called patila (Hindi), patela (Marathi) (attaching a picture)
[image: patila or patela]. In my experience, most Indian households do have a seperate patila/patela for making chai. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you!!! please share a picture if possible; it looks like you were going to but there has been an issue with that.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to, but I just couldn't. I'll figure out a way to attach pictures soon. The image link is in the answer; it seems to be a formatting problem.

Comment: I've tried to access the link directly but get "access denied". You can also drag and drop the image, or upload it to Imgur and take the URL from there.

Comment: Okay, will do ASAP